# Assigning NA based on rle condition in R

Tags: r, na, rle

I have a dataset that shows missing values as 5 or more consecutive repeats. I want to assign these repeated values with `NA`. This is what I have so far, but doing so removes data entirely:

`r <- rle(df$X)`

`df <- df[!rep(r$values & r$lengths >= 5, r$lengths),]`

Is there a way to assign values that satisfy the above condition as `NA`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use -

```
r <- rle(df$X) 
df$X[rep(r$values & r$lengths >= 5, r$lengths)] <- NA
df
```

Also if you are only interested in checking the length of consecutive values you don't need `r$values`.

```
df$X[rep(r$lengths >= 5, r$lengths)] <- NA
```

should work as well.